# Rails 4: redirect_to error when redirecting from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in my recipe's show page i have comments and user can delete a comment. in CommentsController I have destroy method with this code

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @recipe = Recipe.find(@comment.commentable_id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.destroy
      @all_comments = @recipe.comments.recent.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:15)
      format.html do
        flash[:success] = "Comment successfully deleted!"
        redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
      end
      format.js {@recipe_comments = @all_comments}
    else
      format.html do
        flash[:danger] = "Some errors occurred!"
        redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
      end
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

delete URL:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {controller: "comments", action: "destroy", method: :delete, id: comment.id}, class: "close", remote: true %>
```

but when I press Delete I get this error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController)
```

**EDIT**
**Logs**:

```
Started GET "/comments?id=84&method=delete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-25 22:19:20 +0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController):
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/home/jeyhun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/jeyhun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/jeyhun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

this is all my log stack for Delete action.

Comment: All I can see is `recipe` from where the error is coming.. Give the full error track.

Comment: may be a typo, you mentioned in question that you have CommentController but in view you are using "comments" controller.

Comment: @AnilMaurya yes, it's just typo in the post. in real there is CommentsController

Comment: can you show the corresponding JS file of `format.js {@recipe_comments = @all_comments}` ?

Comment: Can you please paste your Rake Routes result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your log , your request is 'Get' Http verb and method=delete is passing as an argument.

Change delete url, move method: :delete out from hash.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {controller: "comments", action: "destroy", id: comment.id}, method: :delete, class: "close", remote: true %>
```